# Make predictions using a tensorflow graph from a keras model

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, keras

I have a model trained using Keras with Tensorflow as my backend, but now I need to turn my model into a tensorflow graph for a certain application. I attempted to do this and make predictions to insure that it is working correctly, but when comparing to the results gathered from model.predict() I get very different values. For instance:

```
from keras.models import load_model
import tensorflow as tf

model = load_model('model_file.h5')

x_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None,7214,1))
y = model(x_placeholder)

x = np.ones((1,7214,1))


with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print("Predictions from:\ntf graph:      "+str(sess.run(y, feed_dict={x_placeholder:x})))
    print("keras predict: "+str(model.predict(x)))
```

returns:

```
Predictions from:
tf graph:      [[-0.1015993   0.07432419  0.0592984 ]]
keras predict: [[ 0.39339241  0.57949686 -3.67846966]]
```

The values from keras predict are correct, but the tf graph results are not.

If it helps to know the final intended application, I am creating a jacobian matrix with the tf.gradients() function, but currently it does not return the correct results when comparing to theano's jacobian function, which gives the correct jacobian. Here is my tensorflow jacobian code:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None,7214,1))
y = tf.reshape(model(x)[0],[-1])
y_list = tf.unstack(y)

jacobian_list = [tf.gradients(y_, x)[0] for y_ in y_list]
jacobian = tf.stack(jacobian_list)
```

EDIT: Model code

```
import numpy as np

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, InputLayer, Flatten
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv1D
from keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling1D
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ReduceLROnPlateau

# activation function used following every layer except for the output layers
activation = 'relu'

# model weight initializer
initializer = 'he_normal'

# shape of input data that is fed into the input layer
input_shape = (None,7214,1)

# number of filters used in the convolutional layers
num_filters = [4,16]

# length of the filters in the convolutional layers
filter_length = 8

# length of the maxpooling window 
pool_length = 4

# number of nodes in each of the hidden fully connected layers
num_hidden_nodes = [256,128]

# number of samples fed into model at once during training
batch_size = 64

# maximum number of interations for model training
max_epochs = 30

# initial learning rate for optimization algorithm
lr = 0.0007

# exponential decay rate for the 1st moment estimates for optimization algorithm
beta_1 = 0.9

# exponential decay rate for the 2nd moment estimates for optimization algorithm
beta_2 = 0.999

# a small constant for numerical stability for optimization algorithm
optimizer_epsilon = 1e-08

model = Sequential([

    InputLayer(batch_input_shape=input_shape),

    Conv1D(kernel_initializer=initializer, activation=activation, padding="same", filters=num_filters[0], kernel_size=filter_length),

    Conv1D(kernel_initializer=initializer, activation=activation, padding="same", filters=num_filters[1], kernel_size=filter_length),

    MaxPooling1D(pool_size=pool_length),

    Flatten(),

    Dense(units=num_hidden_nodes[0], kernel_initializer=initializer, activation=activation),

    Dense(units=num_hidden_nodes[1], kernel_initializer=initializer, activation=activation),

    Dense(units=3, activation="linear", input_dim=num_hidden_nodes[1]),
]) 

# compile model
loss_function = mean squared error
early_stopping_min_delta = 0.0001
early_stopping_patience = 4
reduce_lr_factor = 0.5
reuce_lr_epsilon = 0.0009
reduce_lr_patience = 2
reduce_lr_min = 0.00008

optimizer = Adam(lr=lr, beta_1=beta_1, beta_2=beta_2, epsilon=optimizer_epsilon, decay=0.0)

early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',     min_delta=early_stopping_min_delta, 
                                   patience=early_stopping_patience, verbose=2, mode='min')

reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='loss', factor=0.5, epsilon=reuce_lr_epsilon, 
                              patience=reduce_lr_patience,     min_lr=reduce_lr_min, mode='min', verbose=2)

model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=loss_function)

model.fit(train_x, train_y, validation_data=(cv_x, cv_y),
      epochs=max_epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=2,
      callbacks=[reduce_lr,early_stopping])

model.save('model_file.h5')
```

Comment: i don't really understand your code. can you be a bit more explicit about how you're loading and exporting your code? what does `load_model` do? where is `model` defined? also i think it's dangerous using `global_variables_initializer`, can you be more explicit about how your creating your tensorflow model?

Comment: @maxymoo Thanks for your comment, I've added the code used to create the tensorflow model and corrected the previous code to define the model variable correctly. I agree that using the `global_variables_initializer` is a bit worrisome, but when I don't I receive the error: `FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value dense_14/bias`. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Are you sure it is trained with TF?

Comment: Can you try not to save and load rather predict with TF right after training in the same file?

Comment: @frankyjuang thanks for the suggestion. It is definitely trained with TF as the backend for Keras. Unfortunately, it is necessary for me to save then load the model because it will be used for research and these predictions (using a tf graph) will have to be done time and time again with the same model. Any ideas on how to bypass the `tf.global_variables_initializer()` or how to load the model as a tensorflow graph differently?

Comment: Why do you want to bypass `tf.global_variables_initializer()`? What I mean above is that plz first get rid of the save&load to see if that's the problem.

Comment: @frankyjuang your suggestion did actually work! So there is some problem with saving then loading the model? How can I do this differently so that the predictions from the tf graph match those from keras' `model.predict()` after saving and loading?

Comment: Try [this](https://github.com/amir-abdi/keras_to_tensorflow)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

@frankyjuang linked me to here

https://github.com/amir-abdi/keras_to_tensorflow

and combining this with code from

https://github.com/metaflow-ai/blog/blob/master/tf-freeze/load.py

and

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/675

I have found a solution to both predicting using a tf graph and creating the jacobian function:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# Create function to convert saved keras model to tensorflow graph
def convert_to_pb(weight_file,input_fld='',output_fld=''):

    import os
    import os.path as osp
    from tensorflow.python.framework import graph_util
    from tensorflow.python.framework import graph_io
    from keras.models import load_model
    from keras import backend as K


    # weight_file is a .h5 keras model file
    output_node_names_of_input_network = ["pred0"] 
    output_node_names_of_final_network = 'output_node'

    # change filename to a .pb tensorflow file
    output_graph_name = weight_file[:-2]+'pb'
    weight_file_path = osp.join(input_fld, weight_file)

    net_model = load_model(weight_file_path)

    num_output = len(output_node_names_of_input_network)
    pred = [None]*num_output
    pred_node_names = [None]*num_output

    for i in range(num_output):
        pred_node_names[i] = output_node_names_of_final_network+str(i)
        pred[i] = tf.identity(net_model.output[i], name=pred_node_names[i])

    sess = K.get_session()

    constant_graph = graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(sess, sess.graph.as_graph_def(), pred_node_names)
    graph_io.write_graph(constant_graph, output_fld, output_graph_name, as_text=False)
    print('saved the constant graph (ready for inference) at: ', osp.join(output_fld, output_graph_name))

    return output_fld+output_graph_name
```

Call:

```
tf_model_path = convert_to_pb('model_file.h5','/model_dir/','/model_dir/')
```

Create function to load the tf model as a graph:

```
def load_graph(frozen_graph_filename):
    # We load the protobuf file from the disk and parse it to retrieve the 
    # unserialized graph_def
    with tf.gfile.GFile(frozen_graph_filename, "rb") as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())

    # Then, we can use again a convenient built-in function to import a graph_def into the 
    # current default Graph
    with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
        tf.import_graph_def(
            graph_def, 
            input_map=None, 
            return_elements=None, 
            name="prefix", 
            op_dict=None, 
            producer_op_list=None
        )

    input_name = graph.get_operations()[0].name+':0'
    output_name = graph.get_operations()[-1].name+':0'

    return graph, input_name, output_name
```

Create a function to make model predictions using the tf graph

```
def predict(model_path, input_data):
    # load tf graph
    tf_model,tf_input,tf_output = load_graph(model_path)

    # Create tensors for model input and output
    x = tf_model.get_tensor_by_name(tf_input)
    y = tf_model.get_tensor_by_name(tf_output) 

    # Number of model outputs
    num_outputs = y.shape.as_list()[0]
    predictions = np.zeros((input_data.shape[0],num_outputs))
    for i in range(input_data.shape[0]):        
        with tf.Session(graph=tf_model) as sess:
            y_out = sess.run(y, feed_dict={x: input_data[i:i+1]})
            predictions[i] = y_out

    return predictions
```

Make predictions:

```
tf_predictions = predict(tf_model_path,test_data)
```

Jacobian function:

```
def compute_jacobian(model_path,input_data):

    tf_model,tf_input,tf_output = load_graph(model_path)    

    x = tf_model.get_tensor_by_name(tf_input)
    y = tf_model.get_tensor_by_name(tf_output)
    y_list = tf.unstack(y)
    num_outputs = y.shape.as_list()[0]
    jacobian = np.zeros((num_outputs,input_data.shape[0],input_data.shape[1]))
    for i in range(input_data.shape[0]):
        with tf.Session(graph=tf_model) as sess:
            y_out = sess.run([tf.gradients(y_, x)[0] for y_ in y_list], feed_dict={x: input_data[i:i+1]})
            jac_temp = np.asarray(y_out)
        jacobian[:,i:i+1,:]=jac_temp[:,:,:,0]
    return jacobian
```

Compute Jacobian Matrix:

```
jacobians = compute_jacobian(tf_model_path,test_data)
```

Comment: is there somehow we can fasten up the prediction time by saving the tuple returned by the load_graph() function or maybe even save the tensor values x and y. I just want the prediction to be fast to be able to predict verdict for only one sample.

Comment: @Staretter In predict() function how are you passing the input data(test images) ? From memory or reading directly from disk ?

Comment: from memory. similar to how you pass them into model.predict()