# Convert pre-trained keras model for use by H2O Deep Water?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, h2o

I have a Keras model, in hdf5 format, and I would like to use it for *making predictions with*, from inside H2O Deep Water.

(I am using the tensorflow backend on both Keras and Deep Water, and running the Docker cpu version of Deep Water, though I can switch to the gpu version if that is essential. Deep Water is using Tensorflow 1.1.)

I need to specify `network_definition_file` and `network_parameters_file`. In section 6.5.2 of the [Deep Water booklet pdf](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/booklets/DeepWaterBooklet.pdf) the former has a .meta extension, and the latter has no extension.

I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/44349081/841830 which led me to https://github.com/amir-abdi/keras_to_tensorflow. They appear to be taking a ".h5" file and exporting a ".pb" file. Can I use an ".hdf5" file equally well? And is the ".pb" file the same as the no-extension file shown in the Deep Water docs?

For the meta file I think I need to call the `tf.train.export_meta_graph()` function, giving it a `tf.train.Saver()` object. It looks like [cell 7 of old version](https://github.com/amir-abdi/keras_to_tensorflow/blob/master/old_version/keras_to_tensorflow_via_freeze_graph.ipynb)  is where I could stick that?

The final thing I'm not sure on is how to just use it for prediction. Is the it same as normal H2O deep learning, and you use the `epochs=0` trick? If using the Python API, will I still need the call to `train()` or is creating the `H2ODeepWaterEstimator()` object enough?