# Run trained kaggle model in jupyter notebook

Tags: tensorflow, kaggle

I have build and trained the model in kaggle and have downloaded it's output. How can I now run the trained model locally in jupyter notebook to make prediction ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make predictions using a tensorflow graph from a keras model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44274701/make-predictions-using-a-tensorflow-graph-from-a-keras-model)

Answer (score 2):

You can save your model in a file using:

```
model.save('model.hdf5')
```

Then you can run this in your kaggle kernel:

```
from IPython.display import FileLink
FileLink(r'model.h5')
```

It will then generate a link so you can download your hdf5 file.

In your local jupyter notebook run the following:

```
from keras.models import load_model
model = load_model('model.h5')
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're trying to say How to load pretrained model weights in jupyter.

All you want to do is make a new model in jupyter as the same pretrained model layers and parameters from kaggle. Then use loadweights method. You're ready now to predict now cheers :D

for exmaple:

```
weights_path="donwloaded_weights.hdf5"
model = YourModel()
model.loadweights(weights_path)
model.predict(your_data)
```